# How to make multiple filter in Javascript that connect with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

how to make multiple filter in Javascript if I extract data from Google Spreadsheet?

GS Code

```
var getTable = function(){
  var url = "someURL";
  var script = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("table");
  var html = temp.evaluate().setWidth(1200).setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Leave Application");

}

var include = function(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

  var getTableData = function(){
  var url = "SomeURL";
  var script = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ss = script.getSheetByName("Script");
  var data = ss.getRange(2,2,ss.getLastRow()-1,9).getDisplayValues();

  return data;
}
```

HTML CODE :

```
<head>
<?!= include("table-css");?>
</head>
<body>
            <div>  
               <select id="name">
                    <option disabled selected>Choose Name</option>
                    <option>John</option>
                    <option>Doe</option>
                    <option>Jane</option>
                </select>
               <label>Name Selection</label>
            </div>
      
            <div  class="input-field col s3 right">
               <div> 
               <i id="pending" class="material-icons i1">label_outline</i> 
               <i id="approve" class="material-icons i2">done_all</i>
               <i id="reject" class="material-icons i3">clear</i>
               <i id="notify" class="material-icons i4">error</i>
               
            </div>

          <div>
          <table style="width:100%" id="myTable";>

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type of Leave</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Until</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="table-body">
              
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();

});


function generateTable(dataArray){
  
   dataArray.forEach(function(r){

      var row = document.createElement("tr");

      var col1 = document.createElement("td");
        col1.textContent = r[1];
      var col2 = document.createElement("td");
        col2.textContent = r[2];

       row.appendChild(col1); 
       row.appendChild(col2);
       tbody.appendChild(row);
```

getTableData() is just a function in GS code that return data from spreadsheet.

It will look like this :

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnVIxc7YexQDnVTXihXKjBFtOzMVFK2R/view?usp=sharing]

then in then I used this to start filter;

```
name.onchange = function(){
        
     for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
          if(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent === this.value){
            console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent);
            table.rows[i].style.display = "";

          }else{
            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  } 

var pending = document.getElementById("pending");
    pending.onclick = function(){
      for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
          if(table.rows[i].cells[4].textContent === "Pending"){
             table.rows[i].style.display = "";
             }else{
            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
             }
          }    
    }
```

It working fine for single filter but how to combine both so I can filter based on name and status?

Comment: place use the built-in image uploader.  external images are no stable.

Comment: Can you not simply combine the two conditions with the `&&` operator? How do you retrieve the chosen status? I assume it is set as a value of some DOM element? Hard to say since you are not providing your html code.

Comment: Read the links in the answer you just accepted. Do event delegation  on the parent element do `&&` as ziganotschka suggested.

Comment: @ziganotschka. Sorry I don't quite get it. What do you mean using && operator? Is it combining .onchange && .onclick at the same time or just combine the condition? What I'm trying to do, if I first filter name to Doe it should show Doe's data and table should stay like that and then if I click the status filter icon(filter status to pending), the table should show none because there are no data for Doe-status-pending. I also edited HTML code by the way.

Comment: I meant combining the condition. It would be helpful if you could provide a sample code complete enough to render a functioning webpage.

Comment: @ziganotschka I already added few code. Hope that will give you idea. Consider ldap is the name(dropdown selection). How to combine 2 condition with one trigger. What can I imagine based on &&, it should be .onchange then triggered 2 condition right? That is not what I'm trying to do.